# Hibernate: No session after save of new entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, wicket

I create a new entity, store it the first time and then want to access the collections of the related classes:

```
 @Override
 protected void onSubmit(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form<?> form) {           
        final E entity = (E) form.getModelObject();
        getDao().save(entity); //calls session.saveOrUpdate(entity)
        LOG.debug("Saved entity " + entity);
        LOG.debug("Show collections " + entity.getField().getListOfSomething());
        parent.replaceContentPanel(parent.getDetailsPanel(parent.createReloadableModel(entity)), target);
 }
```

I get the following error on the second line of logging:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: 
no session or session was closed
```

I have also tried

```
Hibernate.initialize(getDetailsModel().getObject().getField().getListOfSomething());
```

This leads to a different error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
```

This is not very surprising when debugging I can see that the collection proxies have no session associated with them.

I am using the 'openSessionInView' filter that comes with the Spring framework. The code works fine by the way when I want to update an existing entity. It also works when I set the fetchType to eager on the collection:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "field", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<E> listOfSomething= new ArrayList<E>();
```

Do I really need to set this to EAGER? I want to avoid this very much and was hoping for a way around it. Is there a way to associate a newly stored entity with the Hibernate session? I have tried both a `session.load(entity)` and a `session.merge(entity)` with no success.

My entities look like this:

```
@Entity class A { 
    @ManyToOne B b;
}

@Entity class B {     
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b") List<A> aList;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b") List<C> cList;
}

@Entity class C {
   @ManyToOne B b;
}
```

What I am doing is creating a `c = new C()`, selecting `b` from a `DropDownChoice` and on submit I want to persist `getDao().save(c)`. After the submit I want to display my new entity on a different panel which is loaded via ajax. For example I want to display `c.getB().getAList()` and that is where the exception happens because the `b`I selected from the `DropdownChoice`is a detached entity and it's `aList` was not fetched and cannot be loaded lazily either.

I cannot figure out how to get the still existing session into my new `C` instance.

Here's more info from my `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>opensessioninview</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>        
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>opensessioninview</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: The 'openSessionInView'-filter you're using, when/where does the transaction start and commit?

Comment: How does your Entity look like? E.g. does the save operation cascade to the collection?

Comment: Please include relevant parts of your web.xml (dispatcher servlet and OpenSessionInView filter)

Comment: What IModel implementation are you using to hold the entity? Have you tried to use a LoadableDetachableModel?

Comment: I am using a LoadableDetachableModel (my own implementation mostly inspired by 'Wicket in Action') in combination with a CompoundPropertyModel

Comment: Try verifying if the active Hibernate Session is the same, when load the object and when you try to save it.

Comment: It's not. That is my question: is it possible to reconnect an object to a new session? If it is impossible it's fine, I'd just like to know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a work-around that allows me to enforce loading the collections I know I will need with `Hibernate.initialize(...)`

```
final ListModel<B> listModel = new ListModel<B>(bList);
for (final B b : bList) {
   Hibernate.initialize(b.getAList());
}
add(new DropDownChoice<B>("b", listModel, new ChoiceRenderer<B>("name", "id")));
```

When I add lines 2-4 from this snippet to my form all instances of `B` that I might later select for my new instance of `C` will have an initialized list of `A`.

I am only half happy with this. I'd still prefer to be able to attach an object to the hibernate session on demand.

Answer (score -1):

An appropriate workaround is to merge() the object that contains the collection before accessing the collection.

Comment: I tried merging the original entity, I tried merging just the related one that contains the collection. neither works -.-